# localhost IIS error - HTTP Error 403.14

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, localhost

I am getting this error when I goto my localhost site that I setup on IIS

`HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.`

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a website setup in IIS? Does it have any docs or dirs in it?

Comment: I do have a website setup on IIS I dont think it has any docs or dirs

Answer (score 1):

You need to [configure the default document in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure IIS so as to point to the landing page of your website.

i.e.

`http://localhost\mywebsite\**index.html**`  <-- or default in some cases